# What is the best way to read GetResponseStream()?

Tags: .net, http, stream, getresponsestream

What is the best way to read an HTTP response from GetResponseStream ?

Currently I'm using the following approach.

```
Using SReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(HttpRes.GetResponseStream)
   SourceCode = SReader.ReadToEnd()
End Using
```

I'm not quite sure if this is the most efficient way to read an http response.

I need the output as string, I've seen an [article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=583) with a different approach but I'm not quite if it's a good one. And in my tests that code had some encoding issues with in different websites.

How do you read web responses?

Comment: Your way seems ok to me. IOW nothing wrong with it.

Comment: BTW code in informit is buggy as one .Read() doesn't mean that you've read all the response hence it'll fail.

Comment: I wish I knew the answer to this. I'm trying to get this right on Android because my implementation is extremely slow. On Android, you don't even get ReadToEnd().

Answer (score 19):

My simple way of doing it to a string. Note the `true` second parameter on the `StreamReader` constructor. This tells it to detect the encoding from the byte order marks and may help with the encoding issue you are getting as well.

```
string target = string.Empty;
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=583");

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
try
{
  StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(),true);                
  try
  {
    target = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
  }
  finally
  {
    streamReader.Close();
  }
}
finally
{
  response.Close();
}
```

Comment: For transferring binary data (like pictures), would it be inefficient to use StreamReader/string and convert to a byte array after? Want to avoid dealing with buffer resizing when reading from a Stream (vs StreamReader)? Would this be bad coding practice, even for small transfers (< 1Mb). What would be best response encoding for binary data (would ASCII be most efficient to convert to a byte array, vs say UTF-8)? Thanks.

Comment: **Answer:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867227/convert-streamreader-to-byte

Answer (score 18):

I use something like this to download a file from a URL:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(localFolder))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(localFolder);   
}


try
{
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Path.Combine(uri, filename));
    httpRequest.Method = "GET";

    // if the URI doesn't exist, an exception will be thrown here...
    using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (FileStream localFileStream = 
                new FileStream(Path.Combine(localFolder, filename), FileMode.Create))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[4096];
                long totalBytesRead = 0;
                int bytesRead;

                while ((bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                    localFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // You might want to handle some specific errors : Just pass on up for now...
    // Remove this catch if you don't want to handle errors here.
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Maybe you could look into the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) class. Here is an example :

```
using System.Net;

namespace WebClientExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var remoteUri = "http://www.contoso.com/library/homepage/images/";
            var fileName = "ms-banner.gif";
            WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri + fileName, fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In powershell, I have this function:

```
function GetWebPage
{param ($Url, $Outfile)
    $request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($SearchBoxBuilderURL)
    $request.AuthenticationLevel = "None"
    $request.TimeOut = 600000     #10 mins 
    $response = $request.GetResponse() #Appending "|Out-Host" anulls the variable
    Write-Host "Response Status Code: "$response.StatusCode
    Write-Host "Response Status Description: "$response.StatusDescription
    $requestStream = $response.GetResponseStream()
    $readStream = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $requestStream
    new-variable db | Out-Host
    $db = $readStream.ReadToEnd()
    $readStream.Close()
    $response.Close()
    #Create a new file and write the web output to a file
    $sw = new-object system.IO.StreamWriter($Outfile)
    $sw.writeline($db) | Out-Host
    $sw.close() | Out-Host
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
$SearchBoxBuilderURL = $SiteUrl + "nin_searchbox/DailySearchBoxBuilder.asp"
$SearchBoxBuilderOutput="D:\ecom\tmp\ss2.txt"
GetWebPage $SearchBoxBuilderURL $SearchBoxBuilderOutput
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to define "buffer" and "totalBytesRead":

```
using ( FileStream localFileStream = ....  
{  
    byte[] buffer = new byte[ 255 ];  
    int bytesRead;  
    double totalBytesRead = 0;  

    while ((bytesRead = ....
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar situation:

I was trying to read raw response in case of an HTTP error consuming a SOAP service, using BasicHTTPBinding.

However, when reading the response using `GetResponseStream()`, got the error:

> Stream not readable

So, this code worked for me:

```
try
{
    response = basicHTTPBindingClient.CallOperation(request);
}
catch (ProtocolException exception)
{
    var webException = exception.InnerException as WebException;

    var alreadyClosedStream = webException.Response.GetResponseStream() as MemoryStream;
    using (var brandNewStream = new MemoryStream(alreadyClosedStream.ToArray()))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(brandNewStream))
        rawResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Sure, using a MemoryStream in conjunction with StreamReader.ReadToEnd() just to decode the UTF8 string from alreadyClosedStream.ToArray() works. But so does `rawResponse = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(alreadyClosedStream.ToArray())`, and it is way more simple and easier to read... ;)