# Epplus Use Template on Web Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, web, epplus

I have been working with epplus on .NET desktop projects (C#) and using templates like this:

```
var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("C:\\Templates\\FormatoReporteSamsung.xlsx"))
```

But now I'working with a .NET Web Project (C#) and i don't know what make to refer to the template that exist like a web resource where the URI of that resource like this:

```
http://myownweb:29200/Content/excelTemplates/Formato.xlsx
```

Comment: Have you tried this?: `var package = new ExcelPackage("http://myownweb:29200/Content/excelTemplates/Formato.xlsx")`

Comment: Yes, it show an error: URI formats are not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I pass the excel template as a stream using this code.

```
using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new MemoryStream(GetBytesTemplate(FullyQualifiedApplicationPath + "Content/excelTemplates/Format.xlsx"))))
    {
        //Write data to excel

        //Read file like byte array to return a response
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/xlsx";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "myFileName" + ".xlsx");
        Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());
        Response.End();
    }
```

To read the excel file has bytes I use this
[Error "This stream does not support seek operations" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434007/error-this-stream-does-not-support-seek-operations-in-c-sharp)

```
private byte[] GetBytesTemplate(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse myResp = myReq.GetResponse();

            byte[] b = null;
            using (Stream stream = myResp.GetResponseStream())
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int count = 0;
                do
                {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    count = stream.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
                    ms.Write(buf, 0, count);
                } while (stream.CanRead && count > 0);
                b = ms.ToArray();
            }

            return b;
        }
```

And to get the name of the website i use 
http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/get-absolut-url-of-asp-net-application/

```
public string FullyQualifiedApplicationPath
        {
            get
            {
                //Return variable declaration
                string appPath = null;

                //Getting the current context of HTTP request
                HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

                //Checking the current context content
                if (context != null)
                {
                    //Formatting the fully qualified website url/name
                    appPath = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}",
                      context.Request.Url.Scheme,
                      context.Request.Url.Host,
                      context.Request.Url.Port == 80
                        ? string.Empty : ":" + context.Request.Url.Port,
                      context.Request.ApplicationPath);
                }
                if (!appPath.EndsWith("/"))
                    appPath += "/";
                return appPath;
            }
        }
```