# How to convert System.IO.Stream into a Texture in Unity for Android?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3, mono

I'm building a client-side Android app in Unity, and when it downloads a jpg from an AWS S3 server, the result comes back as a System.IO.Stream.

However my limited knowledge of Mono and .Net means that I'm struggling to figure out how to turn this System.IO.Stream blob of data into a Texture in Unity, that I can then set on a quad in my scene.

I've seen promising examples of code online like: `var img = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);`
yet System.Drawing.Bitmap is not supported in Unity for Android as far as I can tell - does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

(The exact example code I'm using to download from AWS S3 is the GetObject() function that can be found here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforunity/developerguide/s3.html, but in their example they use a System.IO.StreamReader which only works with reading in text not byte data for images)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the [`LoadImage`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadImage.html) function from the [`Texture2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.html) class. This function converts PNG/JPG image byte array into a texture.

```
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
tex.LoadImage(stream);
```

The `stream` variable must be byte array(`byte[]`) from the internet / AWS S3 serve.

Comment: Thanks @Programmer! Your suggestion to use the LoadImage() function combined with the answer from this question solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434007/error-this-stream-does-not-support-seek-operations-in-c-sharp. 

I was able to get the Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.MD5Stream into a byte[], into a Texture2D!