# Read the response from a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webservice-client

I am calling a web service

```
HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://...");
...
WebResponse res = webReq.GetResponse();
Stream resStream = res.GetResponseStream();
byte[] responseBytes = new byte[resStream.Length];
resStream.Read(responseBytes, 0, (int)resStream.Length);
```

the last line of code throws an exception:

> The stream does not support seek operation.

what should I do to read the response?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error "This stream does not support seek operations" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434007/error-this-stream-does-not-support-seek-operations-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Later I tried using HttpClient instead and it worked.