# How to deserealize custom type using messagepack and tcp sockets?

Tags: c#, tcp, client-server, tcpclient, msgpack

I was trying to send serealized object of custom type on server's side and deserealize it on client's side. I want to do that with Messagepack and tcp sockets. But when the bytes comes to client, programm occurred with error: "Failed to deserealize ". Type has two fields: Name and Age.

Server's side:

```
 var tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
        try
        {
            tcpListener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server is currently run, waiting for incoming connections");
            Person Tom = new Person("Tom",40);
            while (true)
            {
                using var tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                var data = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(Tom);
                await stream.WriteAsync(data);
                Console.WriteLine($"Data was sent to {tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint} client");
                
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            tcpListener.Stop();
        }
```

Client's side:

```
using TcpClient tcpClient= new TcpClient();
await tcpClient.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1",8888);
Console.WriteLine("Client is run");
try
{
    var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    var resData = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(stream);
    Console.WriteLine($"Person's name: {resData.Name} /n Person's age: {resData.Age}");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

How should I deserealize this object correctly? Alreade read topic: [Error "This stream does not support seek operations" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434007/error-this-stream-does-not-support-seek-operations-in-c-sharp). I've got the same mistake, but that doesnt help

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually [Error "This stream does not support seek operations" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434007/error-this-stream-does-not-support-seek-operations-in-c-sharp) helped, the problem was in absent atribute [MessagePackObj] before my type