# Stream was not readable - nothing is disposed of, why does this not work?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
 // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
 string postData = "name=t&description=tt";
 byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
 // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
 request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
 // Get the request stream.
 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.GetRequestStream()))
 {
     string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
 }
```

When the flow hits the using (..... ) statement, I get the following exception:

> Stream was not readable

I want to read the entire request stream into a string, nothing is closed, so the code should work?

Comment: What is `request`? Where do you set its contents?

Comment: Shouldn't you be trying to write to the stream?

Comment: A similar situation was answered and may help, look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43981770/2791237

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write to the Request stream and read from the Response stream.

```
    string postData = "name=t&description=tt";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    // Get the request stream.

    var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
    stream.Write( byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length );
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However, can I not see the xml body of the request which is being sent out?

Comment: @dotnetdev - maybe in the debugger.  In any event, it's not XML, it's simply the string you specified, URL-encoded, so you already have the contents.

Comment: @dotnetdev - if you absolutely had to you could derive your own request class from HttpWebRequest and override GetRequestStream so that it it returned the underlying stream wrapped with a filter.  You could make the filter store the actual request written to the stream and make it available to you via some other property on your class.

Comment: @dotnetdev: There's a very simple way to view network traffic in your .Net application: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The stream is not readable, because it's intended to be written to.  See this link for a simple example:

http://www.netomatix.com/httppostdata.aspx