# Reading AES encrypted message from TCP socket in C#?

Tags: c#, tcp, aes, bytestream

I am using TCP socket in C# sending and receiving encrypted messages using AES encryption algorithm. The problem is when I receive the encrypted message using **stream reader**, it came as `System.byte[]` which I do not know how to read it to pass it to the decryption method.

**this is to send the encrypted message**

```
private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork_1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
       {
           if (client.Connected)
           {
               STW.WriteLine(EncryptStringToBytes(TextToSend,key));
               this.chat_box.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
               {
                   chat_box.AppendText("Me : " + TextToSend + " \n");
               }
               ));
           }
           else
           {
               MessageBox.Show("Failed to send a messege");
           }
           backgroundWorker2.CancelAsync();
       }
```

**this is to receive the encrypted message**

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork_1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (client.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    recieve = STR.ReadLine();  // this message is string
                    // I need to read it as byte format to pass it to Decrytion function                
                    this.chat_box.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
                    {
                        chat_box.AppendText("You : " + recieve + "\n");
                    }
                    ));
                    recieve = "";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

**My problem is here, this message is string
I need to read it as byte format to pass it to Decrytion function**

```
  recieve = STR.ReadLine();  // this message is string
                    // I need to read it as byte format to pass it to Decrytion function
```

Comment: This link may have what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867227/convert-streamreader-to-byte

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use something like [SslStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=net-7.0) to take care of encryption? Implementing your own encryption layer will likely have some type of security issue.