# Use C# to call google GeoLocation and return JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, geolocation

```
public ActionResult GetGeoLocation(string address)
{
    var uri = string.Format(
        "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&sensor=false",
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(address)
        );

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 

    return Json(response);
}
```

This code seems to call out just fine, but it's not returning the proper results? I must be missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reading the response data.

Use [`GetResponseStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) to get the stream containing the body of the response.

```
var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

// read from responseStream
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to get me the right response either. I'm trying to find all the data I would get if I used this http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=8793+s.+carr+way&sensor=false That returns the JSON I need.

Comment: @Mark - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137285/what-is-the-best-way-to-read-getresponsestream/137300#137300