# Getting "Stream not readable" when reading HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, http, c#-4.0, system.net.httpwebrequest

I'm trying to "screen scrape" some data
I have a request as follows (from fiddler)

```
POST http://fallenlondon.storynexus.com/Auth/EmailLogin HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://fallenlondon.storynexus.com/signup
User-Agent: Mine
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Cache-Control: max-age=0
l: 
Origin: http://fallenlondon.storynexus.com/
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: utf-8
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=05xq3gndu4nczvy5wsah5qyw; __utma=100212060.1740063036.1431282067.1431282067.1431284767.2; __utmb=100212060.14.10.1431284767; __utmc=100212060; __utmz=100212060.1431282067.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Host: fallenlondon.storynexus.com
Content-Length: 54
```

(The content is my credentials) - This header matches the request I traced from manually viewing the web page in my browser.

I send this using HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
I get a response back

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 11 May 2015 20:54:15 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Server: Web1
Content-Length: 16900
Connection: keep-alive
```

This (again) matches what I get using the browser.
Using fiddler, I can see the 17k of data (html), I try to read it using...

```
var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
if (stream == null) return null;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
   var data = reader.ReadToEnd();
   reader.Close();
   return data;
}
```

I get an exception on the "new StreamReader" line stating "Stream is not readable"  My debugger shows me that the stream is neither readable or writeable.  This is the 2nd page I have read (the first one being a simple request to the main url to get the login page).  This works fine using the same code.  All streams and requests have been closed after use.

Google gives me no help, suggesting a page error (no, status is 200) or having already read the data (no, code goes straight here)
I am not using threading at all so that's not the issue.
I have tried changing the encoding (requesting gzip gives me a smaller payload as expected but I still can't read it)
I am using c#.net 4.5.2 on win7 x64

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just an FYI, you don't need to close your reader when using a using statement.  Once the using statement loses scope, the reader will automatically close and dispose.  Even with your return inside of it, once you return, it is considered out of scope.

Comment: Have you tried using `StreamReader.Read()` instead of `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`? Maybe "end" is unknown.

Comment: I haven't but... Examining the stream (with the debugger) shows that the stream is not readable, I doubt that this would help

Comment: A similar situation was answered and may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43981770/2791237

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D'oh!
Due to an "oversight" in the code, I was trying to read the stream twice!
All working now

Comment: I don't see where in your code you are `reading the stream twice`.  What exactly is the fix?

Comment: The problem was elsewhere, not actually in this snippet
The program logic was wrong (due to a bit of heavy refactoring)